# Add Row After Particular Class JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have problem with add more button with particular row. It was adding row at last in each row. I discussed my problem in details:

Please See The Code Snipest :

```js
var i = 2;
$(document).on("click",".btn_add",function(){
 var str1 = '<tr><td>'+i+'</td><td>Row '+i+'</td><td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_add">Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_addsub">Add Sub</button></td></tr>';
 
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("tr:last").after(str1);
  i++;
});
$(document).on("click",".btn_addsub",function(){
 var str1 = '<tr><td>'+i+'</td><td>Row '+i+'</td><td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn_remove">Remove</button></td></tr>';
 //$(this).parent().find('tr:last').after(str);
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("tr:last").after(str1);
  i++;
});
$(document).on("click",".btn_remove",function(){
 $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Row</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_add">Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_addsub">Add Sub</button></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

**Problem**

Step 1. Click On Row 1 **Add Sub Button**

Step 2. Again Click On Row 1 **Add Sub Button**

Step 3. Now Click On Row 1 **Add Button**

Step 4. Now Click On Row 4 **Add Sub Button**

That's Working Properly. But Now If I Click On Button **Add Sub Button**  Of Row 1: Then It Will be added after Row 3. Currently it is added after Row 5.

So Please Help Me To Overcome this problem.
Thank You in advance.
One Solution I Tried But No Idea about this : Like Generated Code Will See Like This :

```
<tr class="row_1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_add">Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_addsub">Add Sub</button></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn_remove">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn_remove">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
<tr class="row_2">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_add">Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_addsub">Add Sub</button></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

As per your comment

> Can I add This At Last Of that first tr

, here's a demo:

1) Get all of the trs' index that has `.btn_add`

```
var index = $(this).closest('table').find('.btn_add').map(function(){
  return $(this).closest('tr').index()
}).get()
```

2) Find the index of the current row

```
var thisIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index()
```

3) Find next tr's index from `index` array

```
var nextIndex = index[index.indexOf(thisIndex) + 1]
```

4) If the current index is the last one, then `nextIndex` would be `undefined` and add the new row to the last of the table. Or add the new row before the `nextIndex`'s tr.

```
if(nextIndex)
  $(this).closest('table').find('tr').eq(nextIndex).before(str1);
else
  $(this).closest('table').find("tr:last").after(str1);
```

```js
var i = 2;
$(document).on("click", ".btn_add", function() {
  var str1 = '<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>Row ' + i + '</td><td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_add">Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_addsub">Add Sub</button></td></tr>';

  $(this).closest('table').find("tr:last").after(str1);
  i++;
});
$(document).on("click", ".btn_addsub", function() {
  var str1 = '<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>Row ' + i + '</td><td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn_remove">Remove</button></td></tr>';
  var index = $(this).closest('table').find('.btn_add').map(function(){
    return $(this).closest('tr').index()
  }).get()
  var thisIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index()
  var nextIndex = index[index.indexOf(thisIndex) + 1]
  if(nextIndex)
    $(this).closest('table').find('tr').eq(nextIndex).before(str1);
  else
    $(this).closest('table').find("tr:last").after(str1);
  i++;
});
$(document).on("click", ".btn_remove", function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Row</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_add">Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_addsub">Add Sub</button></td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

I've changed `$(this).parent().parent().parent().find("tr:last").after(str1);` to `$(this).closest("tr").after(str1);`

**Demo**

```js
var i = 2;
$(document).on("click", ".btn_add", function() {
  var str1 = '<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>Row ' + i + '</td><td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_add">Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_addsub">Add Sub</button></td></tr>';

  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("tr:last").after(str1);
  i++;
});
$(document).on("click", ".btn_addsub", function() {
  var str1 = '<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>Row ' + i + '</td><td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn_remove">Remove</button></td></tr>';
  $(this).closest("tr").after(str1);
  i++;
});
$(document).on("click", ".btn_remove", function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Row</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_add">Add</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_addsub">Add Sub</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: But this will added after first tr. Can I add This At Last Of that first tr ??   means after Row 3 and Before Row 4.